# How to stay on php page and display error message on submit form without removing action="ex.php"?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

i'm have a form that's posting to another page. But i'm trying to stay on the same page if the fields are null and display all the error messages instead of going into my action page. Is there a way around this? i have tried using javascript to stop the form from submitting however it is not displaying the error messages. I want to know if this do-able using only php? I know i could just put everything in a page but i'm curious which way is more efficient or how it's suppose to be done? thanks a million

```
register.php

<?php include 'formCheck.php'; ?>
<form method="post" action="add.php">
    <div class="textbox">
            <label for="uname">Username:</label>
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $uerror;?></span>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
```

```
add.php

<?php
require_once "db.php";
if ( !empty($_POST['username'])) {
   $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
   $sql= "INSERT INTO users (username) VALUES ('$u')";
   echo "<pre>\n$sql\n</pre>\n";
   mysqli_query($db,$sql);
   echo 'Success -<a href="index.html">Continue...</a>';
   return;
}
```

```
formCheck.php

<?php 
   $uerror = '';
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
                $uerror = "Username is required";
            }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to help you with this task.

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault(); //prevents from reloading
 // your stuff
 return false;
});
```